# Why does r gc() function report higher memory usage than windows task manager

Tags: r, memory, garbage-collection, taskmanager

I am currently strugling with a sort of large (30M rows, 14+ columns) dataset in r using `data.table` package on my laptop with 8GB ram running 64-bit Win 10.

I have been hitting memory limits all day long, getting the error that R can't allocate slightly over 200MB for a vector. When I look into the Windows Task Manager, I can see, that 2-3GB of RAM are currently at use by R (or about 65% of total, including the system and some other processes). When I run the R `gc()` command, I get the output, that about 7800Mb out of 8012Mb is currently at use.

When I run the `gc()` command for second time, I can see that there was no change in the used memory thanks to previous execution of the `gc`.

When processing the data (i.e executing some `data.table` command), the process uses pretty much all installed memory and writes a thing or two to disk.

What is the reason for the difference between `gc()` output and what I see in task manager? Or to be more precise, why is the number in task manager lower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that windows' native taskmanager only shows physical RAM statistics, it is pretty likely (and from my experience it really is) that the rest of the memory used by R (your "missing" 5-6 Gb) is allocated to the swap file by windows (which is really slow then). You could check this yourself by e. g. using [process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) which I use and also shows the virtual memory (including that on disk).

The memory allocation is done before the end of RAM, certainly with a view to protect the system from crashing. From my experience windows doesn't swap R memory at all, and at a point it's limit is just reached and you get some `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 200 Mb` -- see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46890902/6574038).

I guess you'd like to free memory by `gc()` though the use of running is [controversially discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467201/forcing-garbage-collection-to-run-in-r-with-the-gc-command?lq=1).

If you have no other machine with more RAM and don't like to upgrade your laptop's RAM you could take a look at the topic [cloud computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing).

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a way I could persuade `data.table` to use the disk a bit more during the calculation so that it doesn't need that much RAM?

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried increasing the `memory.limit` to double of what I have actually installed and I suppose it works alright and uses the disk as it should, without making the system go nuts. I was afraid to do that, because I had no idea if R will actually use up to 100% of the physical RAM and then the machine would be basically unusable...

Comment: You could also 1. try to [increase](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/increase-page-file-size-virtual-memory-windows) windows swap file 2. trivially trim your dataset to only the columns you need 3. save it to presumably smaller R-format with `save(mydata, file= "mydata.RData")` restart R and just load it by `load("mydata.Rdata")`. _Incidentially:_ Since R could crash without autosave you may want to save your code before running any probably RAM-intensive command. Good luck!